# Nintex Workflow - Convert string to date + publishing error from InfoPath

Tags: infopath, publish

Ive got two problems that i dont know how to solve.. !

1)
im looking for a way to convert a string variable into a date var in nintex workflow but nothing seems to work?

2)
I have a bunch of forms that I’m publishing to SharePoint. Each of these forms contains a lot of fields, 100+. Till Tuesday evening I never had a problem publishing but all of the sudden I get an error: ‘Updating content file failed’. When I looked it up, I found that apparently it’s because there are too many fields on the form. The solutions I found are:

1)      When publishing making sure you’re not always creating a new column but linking the fields to existing columns. ( and that is in my case correct, so not helpful for me)

2)      Publishing a bunch of fields every time, not all at once. But with over a 100 of fields, you can imagine how long that would take each time I make a change in my form. And even then this solution is not always working.

3)      Publishing to a new created Form Library. First time publishing to a form library it always works. It’s from the second time that it doesn’t anymore. This is what im using now as a solution, but that is also a little crazy, every time deleting and creating a library and importing all the workflows again.

Have you ever encountered this problem and got any other solution that might help me?  Thanksss

Answer (score 0):

For the string conversion, I suggest having a look at this thread on Nintex Connect - it runs through a solution: http://connect.nintex.com/forums/thread/1568.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues but first please tell me two things

1) Do you really want to push all fields from your Main data source to the Form library? You for sure don't want to create views with 100 fields. Normally even if you need all your fields in the flow, you can use integration action Query XML with XPath to get the data you need in the flow. Changing fields is tricky, unfortunately you can't change XML of InfoPath using Nintex Workflow actions unless you create an action that does it for you (I know someone did it) and normally this is indeed done using field propagation with update option. But still think if you need *all* fields on SharePoint side

2) What publishing option do you use? I mean do you create wsp package or use Publish function of InfoPath or do it via central administration?